# How can I reload custom methods to a de-serialized FabricJS object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've been getting familiar w/ FabricJS on a project.

I have a custom class that extends `fabric.Polyline`. This custom class has many custom methods. My problem is : When I serialize the whole canvas and later on load it again with *loadFromJSON()*, **the custom methods are not there anymore...**

I noticed that the object before/after serialization are not exactly the same. Indeed, we can see that after serialization the method `myCustomClassMethod()` is not in the object's `__proto__` anymore :

[image: difference_items]

I know that *loadFromJSON()* has a `reviver()` method for re-adding event listeners, but how can I re-add methods? The [tutorials](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3) say that I need to add a fromObject() method to save/restore objects, I tried playing with that but no luck.

It might also be that my de-serialized object is a "regular" object, and not a fabricjs object instance. But I haven't seen anywhere how to make it a fabric object again.

MRE down below. As you can see, method works if called *before* canvas reloading, but not if called afterwards.

```js
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="treeCanvas")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('treeCanvas', {
    allowTouchScrolling: true,
});

// un-comment log below to inspect objects
canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
    if (e.target != null) {
        //console.log(e.target);
    }
});


// My TreeNode custom class
var TreeNode = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Polyline, {

    initialize: function (X, Y, armsArray, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.armsArray = armsArray;

        this.set({ width: 160, height: 50, originX: 'center', originY: 'center' });
        this.set({ left: this.X, top: this.Y, fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', stroke: 'black', selectable: true });
        this.setCoords();
        this.set({ pathOffset: { x: 0, y: 25 } });

        for (point of this.armsArray) {
            this.points.push({ x: point[0], y: point[1] });
            this.points.push({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        }
    },
    _render: function (ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    },

    // this is the method that disappears after serializing
    myCustomClassMethod: function () {
        this.set({ stroke: 'green' });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});

// Adding an instance of my custom class to canvas
var node1 = new TreeNode(100, 100, [[-80, 50], [80, 50]], []);
canvas.add(node1);
canvas.renderAll();

// node1.myCustomClassMethod(); // method works before serializing + deserializing


var stringifiedCanvas = JSON.stringify(canvas);
canvas.loadFromJSON(stringifiedCanvas, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

node1.myCustomClassMethod(); // method DOES NOT WORK anymore after deserializing
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="treeCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: just a thought, have you considered the security risks of allowing methods to be deserialized and executed? (malicious code could be injected containing an xss attack)

Comment: @melchiar TY for the comment. I really don't know much about that TBH. If I am only serializing/deserializing methods that I defined myself, would it still be a risk?
(I wouldn't be deserializing "outside" JSON files, is what I mean).

Comment: yes, that should be fine. It's only a concern when users are able to submit their serialized canvases which they may have injected code into.

Answer (score 1):

I am **very** far from being a `fabricjs` expert and I do things somewhat differently but you were missing a few important parts (marked with "** CHANGE" in the code below)

Hope this is of some help!

---

```js
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="treeCanvas")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('treeCanvas', {
  allowTouchScrolling: true,
});

// un-comment log below to inspect objects
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  if (e.target != null) {
    //console.log(e.target);
  }
});


// ** CHANGE: define Treenode on the fabric instance
fabric.TreeNode = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Polyline, {

  // ** CHANGE: define the type
  type: 'treeNode',

  initialize: function(X, Y, armsArray, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
    this.armsArray = armsArray;

    this.set({
      width: 160,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    this.set({
      left: this.X,
      top: this.Y,
      fill: null,
      stroke: 'black',
      selectable: true
    });
    this.setCoords();
    this.set({
      pathOffset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 25
      }
    });

    for (point of this.armsArray) {
      this.points.push({
        x: point[0],
        y: point[1]
      });
      this.points.push({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      });
    }
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  },

  // ** CHANGE: export the custom method when serializing
  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      myCustomClassMethod: this.myCustomClassMethod
    });
  },

  myCustomClassMethod: function(x, y, color) {
    // console.log("myCustomClassMethod")
    // console.log(this.myCustomClassMethod)

    this.set({
      left: x,
      top: y,
      stroke: color,
      strokeWidth: 10
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

fabric.TreeNode.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  // console.log(object)
};


var node1 = new fabric.TreeNode(100, 100, [
  [-80, 50],
  [80, 50]
], []);
canvas.add(node1);

canvas.renderAll();

// DESERIALIZE
var stringifiedCanvas = JSON.stringify(canvas);
canvas.loadFromJSON(stringifiedCanvas, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

// ** CHANGE: need to get a reference to the restored object
var restored = canvas.getObjects()[0]
///console.log(restored)
restored.myCustomClassMethod(200, 50, "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <canvas id="treeCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: TYVM for your answer, it's precisely what I was missing! Could you point to me how you knew that I had to use `fabric.TreeNode = ...` ? All of the fabricJS tutorials use for example `var LabeledRect = fabric.util.createClass(...)` when creating custom classes. I suppose it has to do w/ fabricJS's namespace ? I'd be happy to educate myself more on it.

Comment: @EmileHaas – glad to have helped. I honestly don't know if that change is absolutely required if the other "** CHANGED" elements are present (defining a type, etc). The fabricjs tutorial on [subclassing](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#subclassing) doesn't do it that way – but does mention that  a `fabric.labeledRect.fromObject = . . .` method is needed to serialize/restore objects (bottom of linked page) – so maybe they are equivalent? I may have seen the method I used in an answer here. I am **no** fabricjs expert! ;-)